# How to convert array of string into json string in hive?

Tags: arrays, json, string, hive, hiveql

My hive table `test_tbl` has a string field `tag_score`, which contains some json string separated by ";":

```
----------
tag_score |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"keyword":"abc","score": "0.6"};{"keyword":"烟花","score":"0.516409816917747"} |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I extract the correct json from it? The result string should be like this:

```
[{"keyword":"abc","score": "0.6"},{"keyword":"烟花","score":"0.516409816917747"}]
```

I've tried this hive sql:

```
select split(tag, ";") from test_tbl;
```

But I got array of string, not the desired one:

```
["{"keyword":"abc","score": "0.6"}","{"keyword":"烟花","score":"0.516409816917747"}"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to split array and parse struct elements if you want to get array<struct<...>> type. If you just want to get JSON string, all you need is string manipulation: replace and concat.

Replace semicolon between curly brackets with comma, concatenate with square brackets

```
concat('[',regexp_replace(tag_score ,'\\}\073\\{','},{'),']')
```

`\073` - is a semicolon.

If it can be spaces between curly brackets and semicolon, use `'\\}\\s*\073\\s*\\{'` regexp, it will work the same with any number of spaces, like this: `} ; {`